# How to data pass from a java class to JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I have got a question of passing data from javafile to JFrame.

I successfully pass data from JFrame to javafile but not from javafile.

Ex

```
public class classA {
    public void CalenderFile(String filePath) {
        String eventName = "Andy";
        Display dis = new Display();
        dis.seteventName(eventName);
    }
```

================================================

```
public class Display extends JFrame {
    private String eventName; 
    public void seteventName(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }       
    public Display() {
        JTextPane showeventName = new JTextPane();
        showeventName.setText(eventName);                           
        showeventName.setEditable(false);
        showeventName.setBounds(157, 36, 427, 35);
        contentPane.add(showeventName); 
    }
```

However the TextPane show nothing in the result

Comment: You're guilty of magical thinking. Just setting the state of the eventName field is not going to magically change the text displayed in the JTextPane Understand that the JTextPane holds a String object, not the eventName variable, and that is a key misunderstanding that a lot of Java newbies make. You need to explicitly change the text displayed by the JTextPane in your `setEventName` method.

Comment: Again the key misunderstanding here is the difference between a reference variable and a reference. Study this well.

Comment: Also, modifications to widgets need to be properly synchronized.  The usual way to accomplish this is to cause them to be performed on the event-dispatch thread via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` or `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`.  Even having done that, you may furthermore need to instruct the widget that it needs to `repaint()`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels    
@JohnBollinger

Sorry, I don't really get your point. 
As i tried to set the variable `String eventName = "hello";` in the Display.java , the JTextPane with code `showeventName.setText(eventName);` can show "hello" in the textbox. 
Don't understand how is it related to getting the variable in other classes.
BTW Thanks for replying.

Comment: **Again** When you create your JTextPane, you display the String **held by the eventName variable**, the **String**, not the **variable**. When later in the setter method you change the value held by the variable, this has no effect on the String displayed by the JTextPane. It only knows that it holds a String, and this String won't change unless you explicitly tell the JTextPane to display a different String. Again, this is a key understanding that if you don't understand, is something that you should study to understand as it is at the root of how Java works.